# Good book resources (not websites) to learn number theory on my own?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, self-learning, book-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Undergraduate/High-School-Olympiad Level Introductory Number Theory Books For Self-Learning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1774/undergraduate-high-school-olympiad-level-introductory-number-theory-books-for-sel)

I took number theory this semester and loved it but don't feel like I learned all that much. I am not going any farther in formal education in math so I would like to further investigate number theory on my own. Do you have any suggestions for good books? I need at least one that is pretty basic and preferably one that goes a little bit more advanced. (You can look at some of my other recent questions to see the level that I'm at, but I really don't understand much beyond Diophantine equations- pretty much have to start over).

I also would prefer if you didn't recommend current textbooks- I've got a pretty small budget. I was looking at [Ore's Number Theory and its History](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486656209), [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/048646931X), and [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0817645659).

Thanks for the help and I apologize if this question is too broad/vague/or subjective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1. [**Fundamentals of Number Theory** by William Leveque](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486689069). It's a Dover book, so it'll be reasonably priced.
2. [**A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory** by Kenneth Ireland and Michael Rosen](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/038797329X). More pricey (it's a Springer GTM), and pitched at a higher level than LeVeque's.

Comment: I would suggest Solved and Unsolved Problems In number theory by D. Shanks too.