# Number theory for a high school Calculus student?

Tags: reference-request, elementary-number-theory, self-learning

I've always loved playing with numbers, but haven't had any formal guidance in the study of advanced mathematics and number theory. Is there a book (or a few books) on mathematics that I wouldn't have learned in my high school curriculum (algebra, trig, and calculus) that could help me understand higher level maths and get me started on number theory? I know it's quite a broad question, but when I see things like [this xkcd](http://xkcd.com/982/), and in trying to understand concepts I go to Wikipedia articles to find them chock full of terminology that flies over my head, it's quite frustrating.

Comment: http://rutherglen.ics.mq.edu.au/wchen/lnentfolder/lnent.html is a good set of (free) notes on Number Theory.

Comment: The Art of Problem Solving Volume 1 and 2 (especially 2) are nice books which go beyond the standard high school curriculum in general and venture into competition math. They got me interested in higher math.

Comment: If you're asking about book for self-study of number theory, you can find something in related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1774/ (In fact, Stein and Underwood Dudley, which were suggested by Arturo, were mentioned there too.) Maybe you can have a look at questions related/linked to that one too.

Comment: When I was in high school and looking for extras, I stumbled upon, and immensely enjoyed, [Joe Roberts' Elementary Number Theory - a Problem Oriented Approach.](http://books.google.com/books/about/Elementary_number_theory.html?id=RFogAQAAIAAJ) His book has a very unusual style. All the theory is developed as series of exercises. The first half of the book is only definitions and exercises. The second half has hints/solutions/historical remarks. It was a perfect fit for me. Warmly recommend it for self-study.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, you didn't mention the most unusual thing about the Roberts book - it's all done in calligraphy.

Comment: I think I'm starting to love this community

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Books on Number Theory for Layman](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329/books-on-number-theory-for-layman)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That xkcd strip is not about number theory, but about set theory (and a particularly slippery part of set theory at that; the Axiom of Choice is tricky!).

A possible first set theory book might be Halmos's [*Naive Set Theory*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387900926), though it can be tough in parts and suffers somewhat for having few exercises.

There are several introductory Number Theory books; e.g., William Stein's [*Elementary Number Theory: Primes, Congruences and Secrets*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441927522); Leveque's [*Elementary Number Theory*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486663485); and [Underwood Dudley's book of the same title](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/048646931X).