# What is a good book to learn number theory?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, soft-question

What would be a good book to learn basic number theory? If possible a book which also has a collection of practice problems? Thanks.

Comment: You might want to peruse this listing: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329/best-book-ever-on-number-theory?rq=1

Comment: A good place to start might be here:
http://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~abhishek/chicmath.htm

Comment: You might also want to peruse: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1774/undergraduate-high-school-olympiad-level-introductory-number-theory-books-for-se

Comment: It depends on what level you seek and what you already know.

Comment: Right now I am in AP calculus AB.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Good Number Theory books to start with?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548210/good-number-theory-books-to-start-with)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Books on Number Theory for Layman](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329/books-on-number-theory-for-layman)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My two-pennyworth:

1. John Stillwell, *Elements of Number Theory* (Springer 2002). This is by a masterly expositor, and is particularly approachable.
2. G.H. Hardy and E.M. Wright, *An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers* (OUP 1938, and still going strong with a 6th edition in 2008). Also aimed at beginning undergraduate mathematicians and pleasingly accessible.
3. Alan Baker, *A Comprehensive Course in Number Theory* (CUP 2012) is a nice recent textbook (and a lot shorter than its title would suggest, too).

Comment: Thanks. Number two seems to be on my level (taking AP calculus AB at the moment), but what about the other ones?

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised no one has mentioned *Elementary Number Theory* by **David M. Burton** yet.

This book is easy to follow, has lots of illustrative examples, and also comes with a bunch of exercises/practice problems at the end of each section.

In fact, it was exactly this book that introduced me to the topic of *odd perfect numbers* back in the year $1999$.

Answer (score 0):

In my undergrad, we used *Elementary Number Theory* by Kenneth Rosen for our upper level (junior/senior) number theory course. There is also a solutions manual out there, which may be useful if you are self studying the book. To get the most out of the book, you should probably be familiar with the structure of mathematical proofs. For this I recommend the excellent (and free) *Mathematical Reasoning Writing and Proof* by Ted Stundstrom [available here](https://www.tedsundstrom.com/mathematical-reasoning-writing-and-proof).

If you want something more basic, *Discrete Mathemtics*, also by Kenneth Rosen (particularly the first 4 chapters) would also be a good read. It covers proof writing (i.e. creating formal mathematical arguments), elementary mathematical structures (sets, functions), as well as some basic number theory such as:

- Divisibility and Modular Arithmetic
- Integer Representations and Algorithms
- Primes and Greatest Common Divisors
- Solving Congruences
- Applications of Congruences
- Cryptography

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the dover book $\mathit{Number\,\,Theory}$ by George R. Andrews, which is extremely friendly too beginners but also does a good job at giving an overview of all topics in the general "elementary number theory" umbrella.

Counting exercises its a short 300 page read, and cover to cover you could probably get through it in a month or two. I really can't recommend this book enough.