# Looking for a very gentle first book on number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request

My gf is the classic math-phobe, totally traumatized by math, etc., which surprises me, since she's whip-smart.  The only explanation I can think of is that she got off to a bad start in elementary school.

My own love for mathematics was kindled by an old book on number theory that I found in my school's library.  Unfortunately, I can't remember that book's title or author, so...

I'm looking for a *very gentle* first book on number theory.

Comment: If you remember what the cover looked like, you can search "number theory book" on google images.

Comment: @kjo: I wonder if you were thinking of one of the books that is now a [*Dover Number Theory*](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486682528.html) book? There are several and the prices are great! Regards

Comment: I don’t know that I’ve seen anything that I’d call a *very* gentle introduction to the subject, but Underwood Dudley, [*Elementary Number Theory*](http://store.doverpublications.com/048646931x.html) is gentler than most and quite clearly written.

Comment: I second Brian's suggestion of Dudley's book. Also, she might enjoy reading something like Simon Singh's [Fermat's Enigma](http://www.amazon.com/Fermats-Enigma-Greatest-Mathematical-Problem/dp/0385493622), which although is not exactly a book on elementary number theory, it describes the story behind the solution to a famous problem in number theory. For me, before I was even interested in math, it made me want to try to learn what number theory was about.

Comment: Silverman's book A Gentle Introduction to Number Theory is good, serious, unfortunately not cheap.

Comment: You could look at Oystein Ore's [Invitation to Number Theory](http://www.maa.org/ebooks/nml/NML20.html), which is in the MAA's *New Mathematical Library* series and thus roughly written for good high school students.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a good book to learn number theory?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350833/what-is-a-good-book-to-learn-number-theory)