# Highschool level number theory book recommendations

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

What's a good number theory book for me to learn from at a high school level? Our class will study up to Fermat's - Bezout's theorem. I tried other books suggested here, but they are all too advanced. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please clarify: do you already know Fermat and Bezout, or is that the end of what you seek to know?

Comment: Have you looked at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548210/good-number-theory-books-to-start-with) and other posts shown there among linked questions?

Comment: I wish I knew. In Ontario you  can take all the high school math there is and never hear of "number theory"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Good Number Theory books to start with?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548210/good-number-theory-books-to-start-with)

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend the books by Wacław Sierpiński:
[Elementary theory of numbers](http://pldml.icm.edu.pl/pldml/element/bwmeta1.element.dl-catalog-556369c7-b6cc-4a5b-be36-bfc8e0ca7cfa)
and as a supplementary problem book [250 Problems in Elementary Number Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0444000712).

Comment: I think it'd be more helpful to list the titles and authors of the books.  Also, the first link isn't working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Elementary number theory by David M. Burton. It is as said "elementary" and can also be used for self study.