# Material to learn some basic combinatorics?

Tags: combinatorics, book-recommendation, advice

I realize that I'm pretty weak when It comes to basic combinatorics, even with simple things like n choose k I don't feel confident. Furthermore, I've viewed some combinatorics books and the reasoning behind almost all solutions do not make sense to me.

So I'm asking if anyone would advice me on what material to buy or look at to start understanding some basic combinatorics. Keep in mind I'm in high-school. I prefer videos like khan Academy.

Also I figure that because I'm asking this on this site, which is not really of low level, I'm going to get some high level in depth books. But this isn't really what I'm looking for.  I'm just looking to gain an intuition for combinatorics problems.

Comment: Try [mathematics of choice: how to count without counting](http://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/mathematics-of-choice-or-how-to-count-without-counting).  Here is a [link to a google preview](https://books.google.com/books/about/Mathematics_of_Choice.html?id=IOO0s7-ScZEC).

Comment: This video series explains not only the basics, but also why our mind finds it hard, in what way, and how to overcome the hardships:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QrfA8mKOIjI

Also, an elementary and thorough exposition, from the ground up, can be found in this little book:
https://www.amazon.com/Discrete-Mathematics-Highschooler-Alexander-Sadovsky/dp/1453869670/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1469220406&sr=8-1&keywords=sadovsky+discrete+mathematics

Comment: Thanks ${}{}{}{}{}$ @avs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undergrad-level combinatorics texts easier than Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1454339/undergrad-level-combinatorics-texts-easier-than-stanleys-enumerative-combinator)

Answer (score 2):

Concrete Mathematics by Donald Knuth. I think everyone who hasn't tried this book should see it.

Answer (score 2):

Enumerative Combinatorics by Richard Stanley [Volume 1](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/ec1/), and Volume 2.

Answer (score 0):

For beginners, AoPS(Art of Problem Solving)'s Introduction to Counting and Probability provides stable basics and introduces proofs.  AoPS also offers an online community to discuss math, online classes, and counting videos.