# Introduction to combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request

Are there lecture notes on the internet (or even books) with an introduction to combinatorics using the modern language as in the book Analytic Combinatorics by  Philippe Flajolet and Robert Sedgewick or the introduction to combinatorics in the handbook of enumeration by ardila?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undergrad-level combinatorics texts easier than Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1454339/undergrad-level-combinatorics-texts-easier-than-stanleys-enumerative-combinator)

Answer (score 0):

Two online courses from Coursera, both taught by Robert Sedgewick:

[Analysis of Algorithms](https://www.coursera.org/learn/analysis-of-algorithms) based on the textbook *An Introduction to the Analysis of Algorithms* by Sedgwick and Flajolet

[Analytic Combinatorics](https://www.coursera.org/learn/analytic-combinatorics#) based on the book by the same title

"Analysis of Algorithms" should be viewed as a prerequisite to "Analytic Combinatorics".  I've taken both courses, and my sole criticism is that there is so much to read in "Analytic Combinatorics" that's it's almost impossible to do the readings and assigned exercises and keep on schedule.  But so what, no one is looking over your shoulder.  Highly recommended.