# Good Combinatorics book

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, book-recommendation

I need suggestions for good Combinatorics book which must have following topics covered in depth:

1. Recurrence relations
2. Bell numbers and Bell polynomials
3. Stirling numbers and Stirling polynomials
4. Partition of sets and numbers

Comment: You may find the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1454339/undergrad-level-combinatorics-texts-easier-than-stanleys-enumerative-combinator?noredirect=1&lq=1) helpful.

Comment: If you are looking for an *in-depth* study of combinatorics I will always recommend Stanley's [Enumerative Combinatorics](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/ec1/) (pdf of Vol. 1 freely available) which covers these and many, many other topics.  However it can be rather dense and it may be a tough read depending on your 'mathematical maturity'.  For a gentler introduction, I like Peter Cameron's [Combinatorics: Topics, Techniques, Algorithms](https://www.amazon.com/Combinatorics-Techniques-Algorithms-Peter-Cameron/dp/0521457610)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Good Book On Combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15201/good-book-on-combinatorics)