# Soft Question: Resources to learn Olympiad Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, soft-question, contest-math, book-recommendation

Combinatorics is my weakest Math Olympiad subject and nine out of ten times I am unable to solve a combinatorics problem from my country's mathematical Olympiads (India). I do not have a tutor nor any resources except the internet and AoPS to learn and therefore I need some introductory problem-solving texts to get me going.

I currently know about basic counting principles, linear homogeneous recurrence relations, binomial-theorem, multinomial theorem, basic graph theory, etc. I am referring to Richard A. Brualdi's Introductory Combinatorics as my primary textbook.

What I need now is some Olympiad problem-solving texts or readings which cover everything from the basics to advanced problems. Please suggest some reading material assuming I am a beginner in Olympiad Combinatorics and have no prior knowledge about it.

Thank you.

Edit: I researched and found Chen Chuan Chong's Principles and Techniques in Combinatorics and Titu's Guide to UG Combinatorics. Are these two good books? I am finding the latter one very hard to grasp.

Comment: Past putnam exams are good, tough problems that you can study. There are worked out solutions for past exams all over the internet.

Comment: use Mathlinks, there are many problems and articles

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1454339 , specifically [Andreescu and Feng](https://books.google.de/books?id=60rb-NF-uvYC&printsec=frontcover&dq=A%20Path%20to%20Combinatorics%20for%20Undergraduates,%20by%20Titu%20Andreescu&source=bl&ots=wutA-jSIvk&sig=9g6WslFnhgcBzhSAD8c7d8H2dWg&hl=en&ei=EkmBTaDZCYqBOt_LibsI&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: Try going through my link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1b5m7Wb07z_faWDWS_Yv1359n_bdIMEj7 - I am bound to have 1-2 books (minimum) that could help. Happy hunting!