# Best books for combinatorics for beginner

Tags: combinatorics, book-recommendation

Best books for combinatorics for beginner

Im weak in combinatorics I need  a basic books for combinatorics
that  books must  contain given below Topics

$1.$Elementary combinatorics,

$2.$combinatorial probability,

$3.$ pigeon-hole principle,

$4.$inclusionexclusion principle.

Comment: Concrete Mathematics by Donald Knuth et al is very good

Comment: I disagree: concrete math is not so good for beginners and doesn't have so much by way of counting (and no bijective proofs). instead, try Merris's book Combinatorics, or Alan Tucker's Applied Combinatorics.

Comment: I'd also recommend [The Art of Problem Solving Introduction to Counting and Probability](https://artofproblemsolving.com/store/item/intro-counting?gtmlist=Bookstore_Home)

Comment: *Concrete Mathematics* is a splendid book, but it is definitely **not** appropriate here. Tucker (mentioned above) has a lot of graph theory and may be at slightly too high a level. Edward Scheinerman, *Mathematics: A Discrete Introduction* would be a better choice than either at the level that I think is wanted here.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1454339/undergrad-level-combinatorics-texts-easier-than-stanleys-enumerative-combinator/1454420 has some references (note that I don't really know which of them are beginner-friendly; it's been a while since I was a beginner).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undergrad-level combinatorics texts easier than Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1454339/undergrad-level-combinatorics-texts-easier-than-stanleys-enumerative-combinator)

Answer (score 1):

The Art and Craft of Problem Solving by Paul Zeitz has a nice section on combinatorics with plenty of motivation.

Answer (score 1):

Cameron's **Combinatorics:Topics,Techniques,Algorithms**

This actually is not much of a book for a pro.But it does bode well for starters.
Here is the link
**[https://www.amazon.com/Combinatorics-Techniques-Algorithms-Peter-Cameron/dp/0521457610](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521457610)**

Well known book among graduatees...