# Cleaner form for transformation involving Stirling numbers

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers

I have a specific transformation involving treating the Stirling numbers of the first kind as a matrix, given by, for some positive $b$

$$
C^{(b)} = (S_1^{(b)})^{T} \left(J_b\ \left(\frac{1}{2^{i}}{{b}\choose{i}}\right) \right) S_1^{(b)}
$$

where $S_1^{(b)}$ is a $b+1 \times b+1$ matrix of Stirling numbers of the first kind, $J_b$ is the [exchange matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_matrix) (matrix with 1s along the anti-diagonal), and the remaining matrix is simply a diagonal matrix with binomial coefficients divided by powers of two along the diagonal

schematically, this looks like, for example for $b=2$,

$$
C^{(2)} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 &  0 &  0 \\
 0 &  1 & -1 \\
 0 &  0 &  1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2^{2}}{{2}\choose{2}} \\
 0 & \frac{1}{2^{1}}{{2}\choose{1}} & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{2^{0}}{{2}\choose{0}} & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 &  0 & 0 \\
 0 &  1 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and the specific matrix elements are given by

$$
c^{(b)}_{k l} = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2^b} s(b, l) & k = 0 \\
s(b, k) & l = 0 \\
\sum_{w=l}^{b-k} \frac{1}{2^w} {{b}\choose{w}} s(b-w, k) s(w, l)   & else
\end{cases}
$$

Given the connections between changes of basis to rising/falling factorials, Stirling numbers, and binomial coefficients this *feels* like it has some deeper meaning, but this is of course complicated by the fact that we can't read this as a plain change of basis since $S_1^{(b)}$ is not unitary

For anyone who wants it, here's some Mathematica code to generate this matrix

```
cMat[b_] :=
 With[
  {
   S = Table[StirlingS1[k, w], {k, 0, b}, {w, 0, b}],
   J = Array[KroneckerDelta[#, b - #2] &, {b, b} + 1, 0],
   W = DiagonalMatrix[Table[Binomial[b, w]/2^w, {w, 0, b}]]
   },
  Transpose[S] . (J . W) . S
  ]

cMat[3] // MatrixForm
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & \frac{1}{4} & -\frac{3}{8} & \frac{1}{8} \\
 2 & -\frac{9}{4} & \frac{3}{4} & 0 \\
 -3 & \frac{3}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Combinatorial interpretation:**

Let $\Sigma_b$ represent the collection of colored permutations of the following kind: for a permutation $w$ of $\{1, \ldots, b\}$, its cycles are marked either "colored" or "uncolored", and if $x$ is an entry in a colored cycle then $x$ is colored either red or blue.

For example, when $b = 2$, there are 14 colored permutations in $\Sigma_2$: five have underlying permutation $(12)$ (one in which the cycle is uncolored, four in which the cycle is colored) and nine have underlying permutation $(1)(2)$.

The rescaled matrix entry $2^b \cdot |c^{(b)}_{kl}|$ counts the permutations in $\Sigma_b$ that have $k$ colored and $l$ uncolored cycles, while the checkerboard sign pattern just tracks the parity of those permutations.

**Generatingfunctionology:**

You ask about connections with falling/rising factorials; to me that's really a question about the generating function for these numbers.  For a fixed $b$, we can define the following bivariate generating function:
$$
F_b(x, y) = \sum_{k = 0}^b \sum_{\ell = 0}^b c^{(b)}_{k, \ell} x^k y^{\ell}.
$$
One could compute formulas for this either from the combinatorial interpretation or directly from the formula you gave:
\begin{align*}
F_b(x, y) & = \sum_{k = 0}^b \sum_{\ell = 0}^b \sum_{w = \ell}^{b - k} \frac{1}{2^w} \binom{b}{w} s(b - w, k)s(w, \ell) x^k y^{\ell}  \\
& = \sum_{w = 0}^b \frac{1}{2^w} \binom{b}{w} \sum_{k = 0}^{b - w} s(b - w, k) x^k \sum_{\ell = 0}^w s(w, \ell) y^\ell \\
& = \sum_{w = 0}^b \frac{1}{2^w} \binom{b}{w} (x)_{b - w} (y)_{w}.\end{align*}
There are lots of fun ways that one can rewrite this; for example, it is equal to $$b! \cdot \sum_{w = 0}^b \frac{1}{2^w} \binom{x}{b - w} \binom{y}{w}.$$  If it weren't for the power of $2$, this would be Vandermonde's identity, but as it is it does not factor further in general.  We can also compute the natural *tri*variate generating function
$$
F(x, y, z) = \sum_{b \geq 0} F_b(x, y) \frac{z^b}{b!},
$$
and from the previous equation we have
\begin{align*}
F(x, y, z) & = \sum_{b \geq 0}\sum_{w = 0}^b \frac{1}{2^w} \binom{x}{b - w} \binom{y}{w} z^b \\
& = \sum_{w \geq 0} \frac{z^2}{2^w}\binom{y}{w} \sum_{b \geq w} \binom{x}{b - w} z^{b - w} \\
& = \sum_{w \geq 0} \left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^w \binom{y}{w}  \cdot (1 + z)^x \\
& = \left(1 + \frac{z}{2}\right)^y (1 + z)^x,
\end{align*}
which is rather nice.

Comment: That's interesting. I've never bothered with colored permutations (which seem like just adding an extra dimension to standard ones?). Is there a way to cast this in terms of the rising or falling factorials? Alternately, does this interpretation lead to a more convenient method for calculating these?

Comment: @b3m2a1 Sometimes having a combinatorial model is useful -- for example, if you wanted to compute row or column sums (say of the positive part) it would explain why the answer will factor nicely.  I have added some generating functions you might like.

Comment: That's pretty neat. This produce the matrix elements of the powers of a particular type of sparse, formally infinite dimensional matrix and the binomial and rising factorial forms of $F_b$ in particular are useful. I'll need to see what connections I can make with that trivariate form though since it definitely seems to have some deeper implications with my underlying problem

Comment: Do you have any recommendations for references to get more comfortable with this kind of sequence manipulation? I have a related problem (three term recurrence generating a matrix) that would probably benefit from many of the same approaches

Comment: Well the standard reference for things generatingfunctionological is probably Wilf's generatingfunctionology https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html ; I like Sagan's new book https://users.math.msu.edu/users/bsagan/Books/Aoc/GSM210.pdf too but it is broader in scope.

Comment: @b3m2a1 This answer might also be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1454339/undergrad-level-combinatorics-texts-easier-than-stanleys-enumerative-combinator