# How is $a \equiv b \pmod m $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, equivalence-relations

Lets say $a = 14, b = 20, m = 6$

$a \equiv b \pmod m $

$ 14 \equiv 20 \pmod 6$

$14 \equiv 2 $ is not true?

Because $20 \pmod 6 = 2$?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it is, $14\pmod 6 = 2$

Comment: Did you mean to have a $\pmod 6$ on the line with $14 \equiv 2$?  It seems like you meant it to be there.

Comment: $14 = 2\times 6 +\color{blue}{2}$, and $20 = 3 \times 6 + \color{blue}{2}$, and $2 = 0\times 6 + \color{blue}{2}$.  $\quad 2, 14, 20\;$ are all congruent, modulo $6$.  (As is $8 = 1\times 6 + 2$...etc)

Comment: You might like to read over [this question and answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1907763/is-it-trying-to-say-that-operatornamemod-7-is-neither-associated-with-29/1907887#1907887)

Answer (score 1):

$14 \equiv 2 \pmod 6$ is true.  $14-2=12$ is divisible by $6$.  Why do you think it is not true?

Comment: Oh i didn't realize the mod m applied to both sides? Wait so what is the final answer on both sides? 2 is equivalent to 2?

Comment: $\pmod m$ defines what we mean by equivalent.  I would say it applies to the equivalence sign, not to either side of it.  You can reduce each side to a representative, which we usually take to be one of $0,1,2,\ldots m-1$ and here is $2$.

Comment: So is $a \equiv b \pmod m$ the same as $a\mod m \equiv b \mod m$?

Comment: I have only seen the left version in math.  Computers regard mod as an operator and often write it $\%$.  In that case one should write the second as $a\%m=b\%m$ or $a \bmod m = b \bmod m$ because you are computing the representative, but it is a fine point.  I think most people would accept your second version.

Answer (score 0):

$14$ and $20$ differ by a multiple of $6$. So do $14$ and $2$. All three are congruent modulo $6$.

Comment: So is $a \equiv b \pmod m$ the same as $a\mod m \equiv b \mod m$?

Comment: @JamesMitchell Yes, although it's not usually written that way. You'd probably say $a \pmod m = b \pmod m$ if you wrote it at all. Just $a \equiv b \pmod m$ is standard.