# Reference for very basic books in Number theory

Tags: reference-request

I'm confused about which books I have to read for Elementary number theory for the beginner level.

I need references for  very basic books  in Elementary number theory  and that book  must contain given Topics below

$ 1.$Divisibility

$2.$ congruences

$ 3$ .standard arithmetic functions

$4.$ Combinatorics permutations and combinations.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?client=ms-android-motorola-rev2&sxsrf=ALeKk03ipv3W5j5MJT55dFq6VGbfQkepYA:1598384155520&q=Number+theory+books&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAOOQMRLOK81NSi1SKMlIzS-qVEjKz88ujhJJKi0qyc9TQJE7xcirn65vaJiWVVyZaxxfAOMnVRakZRjmAeW59HP1DdLLyopycqEcs_SK-JSSU4w8IJVGSbnGlikp6TC5YvO0sjKYKelGJoUGOcXZUMlkw5L4rCyYxnIDQ_PK3CyEOSZZZQVGvxiF_TAd38DCuIgVmwQAw1RHP-0AAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjTrLf-jLfrAhUCzzgGHfAJAHIQ4qYDMAd6BAgXEBg&biw=360&bih=568

Comment: thanks u @DietrichBurde yes

Comment: https://bookstore.ams.org/mbk-105/   this recent one is very, umm, visual

Comment: A more apposite duplicate is https://math.stackexchange.com/q/725011.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying Vinogradov's little book, mostly because it fits my budget.  I like it so far.  Published by Dover.

Wanted to get Alan Baker's book.  Heard it is good.  He's a professor at Cambridge, and won a Fields Medal.  Am putting it off for now.

If the title is any indication, *the Higher Arithmetic* by Davenport will be good.  I've heard it is.

I know first hand about Silverman's Friendly Introduction.  I read alot of it.  I recommend it.  It's fun; though actually intended to sort of convert non-math majors.