# Where Can I Find a List of Common, or all, Definitions related to Proofs

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, proof-explanation

For instance, the definition of Divides, Divisor, Multiple is as follows.

A nonzero integer m divides an integer n provided that there is an integer q such that n=m⋅q. We also say that m is a divisor of n, m is a factor of n, and n is a multiple of m. The integer 0 is not a divisor of any integer. If a and b are integers and  a≠0, we frequently use the notation a|b as a shorthand for “a  divides b.”

I've just started learning proofing techniques, and along the way the reading material I use occasionally throws a definition my way that is helpful for a certain proof. I was wondering if there is sort of a centralized database, or glossary, of these definitions that I can refer to when trying my hand at proofs -- so I can use them as reference.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: First you have to identify the mathematical "topic". In your case it seems to be "Elementary Number Theory". Then you can find such databases online, or more explicitly in lecture notes or in course notes with examples for such proofs - see for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548210/good-number-theory-books-to-start-with) for help.

Comment: Okay, great! That makes total sense. Thank you!

Comment: I think another good resource is to simply read the wikipedia entry for the particular term/object. The website 'Proofwiki' is sort of a 'centralised database', in that it collects a number of proofs and definitions. I think you'll find most elementary definitions there, even if they are a bit verbose.

Comment: Ok cool, thanks!