# what is a good book (about number theory)

Tags: number-theory

I find a good books for number theory...

An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers (by G.H hardy)or Burton, Rosen..etc

is it good?? (i want a book which best of best in number theory)

i want a lot of theorm and background. etc.

(level is under~~graduate)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329/best-book-ever-on-number-theory?rq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350833/what-is-a-good-book-to-learn-number-theory?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

For a more computational introduction and definitely manageable to work through on your own, I would suggest one of "A Friendly Introduction to Number Theory" or "Elementary Number Theory by Jones and Jones". I prefer the former, as it get's to some pretty complex stuff (elliptic curves by the end I think). The Jones and Jones is good too though, and manages to sneak a little introductory algebra without you noticing.

If you're looking for more of light read with fewer (maybe none?) exercises, "Higher Arithmetic" is good and helpful for background and intuition for some of the intro concepts.

Note that none of the above assume really any machinery from college math, just some maturity.

Comment: thanks your suggest .. i will.. buy  A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory  Ireland, Kenneth/ Rosen, Michael | Springer anyway your answer is cool!