# Analytic number theory books after Apostol

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory

I am planning to learn some classical results on analytic number theory. I have read  Apostol's *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory*, but nothing about algebraic number theory. Can anyone recommend some more advanced books with further results on analytic number theory?

Comment: Maybe you can peruse http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153022/a-good-reference-to-begin-analytic-number-theory?rq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29056/supplemental-number-theory-text-to-montgomery-and-vaughan

Answer (score 10):

Are you aware that Apostol: Introduction to Analytic Number Theory. continues with Volume 2, Modular Functions and Dirichlet Series in Number Theory.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, Davenport's book (Multiplicative Number Theory) is great, as is Serre's (Course in Arithmetic) Once you read those, check out Iwaniec/Kowalski.