# References for Algebraic Number Theory and Class Field Theory

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, schemes, class-field-theory

My long term goal for this "reading/study project" is to understand roughly what the Langlands conjectures are about. A more modest short term goal though, and more realistic one, is to understand:

1) the basics of Algebraic Number Theory, with a lot of examples worked out,

2) the basics of class field theory, but explained from a modern point of view, using adeles and ideles, eventually. However, I would like the abstraction to be gradual, so to speak, and motivated by a few worked out examples.

My background includes of course the usual Graduate Algebra courses, but I did read on my own quite a bit of commutative algebra and algebraic geometry. So I know what is a Noetherian ring, localization, the ring of integers in a number field, a UFD, a PID, the Galois group etc. I would like to know more about Dedekind domains and "onwards".

I would possibly like references that make analogies with algebraic geometry say, via schemes, for instance (I know the basics of schemes but I prefer an approach with many examples, kind of like, say, Eisenbud and Harris's book "The Geometry of Schemes", but with more examples worked out on the Algebraic Number Theory side).

I realize that my requirements may not all be met at once, but I will take whatever I can get, so to speak, in terms of advice and recommendations. Thank you!

Comment: From what you're describing, Neukirch's book could be a good start. Or Milne's notes

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90972/learning-roadmap-for-class-field-theory-and-more

Comment: J.S. Milne's [Algebraic Number Theory](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ANT.pdf) and [Fields and Galois Theory](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FT.pdf)

Comment: And, when you get to it, Benedict Gross's (youtube) Eilenberg lectures are a great intro to the Langlands program....

Comment: @Mathmo123, yes, I have stumbled on Milne's notes, and love them. Thank you for Neukirch's book. I will check it out. lhf, thank you, yes I just checked 2 posts which ask for references for class field theory. It seems each one would like to learn things in a certain way, but only a limited number of books/approaches are available.

Comment: @peterag, thank you! Yes, eventually, I would like to get there!

Comment: @emma, yes, I stumbled on Milne's website, and I find it full of useful lecture notes! It is http://jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/index.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thank everybody for their comments. I have decided to use Milne's lecture notes http://jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/index.html. I am starting with his algebraic number theory notes for now. It would take a while before getting to the Langland's program, but anyway, the process is fun. I appreciate more now the definition of Dedekind domains, which, from what I understand, took a while to formulate as the right setting for the rings of integers in number fields for instance (talking as a non-expert of course).

Edit: Neukirch's book is really nice by the way. I am now reading parts of it. Thank you @Mathmo123 for suggesting it, and I thank Prof. Khuri-Makdissi for also suggesting it (among others).