# Resources for Abelian Equations

Tags: reference-request, galois-theory

I am taking a Galois Theory course using Cox's Galois Theory [text book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118072057), and we have a required student project.  Having read the section on Abelian Equations, section 6.5 page 143, I want to know more about them.  Unfortunately, I can't find any resources for further reading using google or my college's library search.  Do Abelian Equations go by a different name now, or is there not much interesting theory to follow up the book's presentation?  Are there any links or books I can follow up with?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The book ends its short section on Abelian Equations with the statement of the Kronecker–Weber theorem. The natural follow up from this point is [Class field theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_field_theory), which studies abelian extensions. An excellent introduction is the book [Primes of the Form $x^2+ny^2$](https://dacox.people.amherst.edu/primes.html), also by Cox. See also the question [Learning roadmap for Class Field Theory and more](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90972/learning-roadmap-for-class-field-theory-and-more).