# good number theory

Tags: reference-request

There may be mistakes by grammar since I do not live in English-spoken-world.

I am looking for a book on number theory (in English) . If the book is mainly written about number theory, I do not mind whether one is text or reading.Remark; Reading is book including an anecdote etc.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329/best-book-ever-on-number-theory?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

[An introduction to Number Theory by Ivan Niven,Herbert S.Zuckerman,Hugh L. Montgomery](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=V52HIcKguJ4C&printsec=frontcover&dq=niven+number+theory+books&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Py3cUfaQH8vKrAfkx4G4Aw&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAQ)

[Number Theory: An Approach Through History from Hammurapi to Legendre
 By André Weil](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=d32SGbHnMKcC&printsec=frontcover&dq=books+on+number+theory+history&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qS7cUYGoH4mYrgezh4GIAQ&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=books%20on%20number%20theory%20history&f=false)