# Book/website for an introduction to modular arithmetic

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, modular-arithmetic, book-recommendation

Some questions here are answered exclusively by using modular arithmetic. Especially those involving number theory. Suggest some books or websites where I can learn enough modular arithmetic so as to solve/understand solutions of these questions on number theory.

Comment: See my answer (and others) here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1341222/elementary-number-theory-prerequisites/1341258#1341258

Comment: Any introductory book to number theory will suffice. Try 'Elementary number theory' by David M Burton.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Books on Number Theory for Layman](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329/books-on-number-theory-for-layman)

Answer (score 0):

I have the book "An Adventurer's Guide to Number Theory" by Richard Friedberg. It deals mostly with basics. One chapter is about modular arithmetic. It contains a lot of examples.